# This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am inserting data in my form but it is not updated in database. When I refresh the table data I am getting this error:

> This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility.

There are no errors in my code. According to other articles I set the "Copy to Output Directory" property of database to "Copy if Newer" too. Still it is giving me this error. How can I fix this error? What changes should I make? I am using visual studio 2015 and local database.
 This is my connection string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="dbx"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Normally you only get that message when taking say a database of version x, and trying to load it on an earlier one.

Comment: LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express. Perhaps the database file was created with a *newer* version of SQL Server Express than the one installed on your machine?